# How to signal on the minimap in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Nothing to add to the title of the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

2 Ways:

- Alt+G, then click *(can be changed to a different key in the keybindings)*
- Ctrl+Alt+Click *(can be changed to a different key in the keybindings)*
- Click on the ping icon next to the minimap, then click.

The clicking can be done either in the game window, or on the minimap.

---

The Keybindings can be found under:

Menu->Options->HotKeys->Global->Unit Management

And either:

- Ping Minimap
- Quick Ping
- Choose Ping Target

Also, you can click directly at the game window, no need to go to the minimap (even though the keybinding says "Ping Minimap"

Comment: Why is this down voted? This is correct.

Comment: Agreed. It is correct.

Comment: After alt-g you can either click on the minimap or on the game window itself.

Comment: You should really add what Oak said to your answer. If you want you  want to ping something you are looking at its easier to click it then the mini map most of the time.

Comment: As of patch 1.5 you may need to use control-option to quick ping, unless you rebind the hotkey in options (global hotkeys, under unit management).

Comment: This answer is no longer correct! Alt+Click has been disabled as a way to ping the minimap. Alt+G is the same as clicking on the ping icon (in both cases it takes 2 steps to ping the minimap whereas the alt+click was one fluid step). You cannot rebind alt+click to the ping action, but you can do something similar (such as Ctrl+Alt+Click).

Comment: @WallaceBrown Thanks for the note here. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @WallaceBrown It still works, but it has to be bound to that. The default is Ctrl+Alt+Click, but I have mine bound to Alt+click now.

Answer (score 10):

Two ways:

Click the Ping icon (looks like radio waves, sorta like ((•)) ), then click anywhere in the minimap.

Press Alt+G on the keyboard, then click anywhere in the minimap.

Comment: The ping shows an exclamation mark that is the same color as your units, so everyone on your team can tell it was you that pinged.

Comment: I miss the "just hold alt" of WC3

Comment: As stated before, just hold alt and click on the minimap.

Comment: @tzenes that can be turned on

Answer (score 2):

1) You can hold alt and click on the minimap.

2) Hold alt + g and click on the map.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + Click or <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> + click for Mac

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the keybindings in the menu - for example, I changed my ping back to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Left-Click.

Patch 1.5 also modified the behavior so that you could ping your minimap by ping-clicking on the actual playfield you're looking at. Thus you no longer have to mouse down to the minimap, find your current view location, and then ping - you can simply ping-click the main playfield in front of you and the ping appears on their minimap at the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

In patch 1.5 Blizzard changed the default keyboard mapping such that holding alt and clicking on the map or minimap no longer worked. To revert this change, load up the hotkeys dialogue and look for Quick Ping in Global - Unit Management and simply change this back to alt.